# Maximum quality of video with Flex AIR

Tags: apache-flex, video, air, video-capture

I want to use a camera which is installed in my computer in a Flex AIR application i'm writing, and I have few questions regarding the quality options :

1. Do I have any limitation on the video image quality? If my camera supports HD recording, will I be able to record in HD format via the AIR application?
2. How can I export the recorded video in any format I want?
3. If I want to use the same camera for shooting stills, how can I ensure (within the code) the best quality for the result pictures ?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Air can play 1080p no prob, however it cannot 'record' it from the application. There are [some workarounds](http://www.zeropointnine.com/blog/webcam-dvr-for-apollo/) but you won't have sound.  This is something that the OS should handle.

2) You can't, see above.

3) Shooting stills with a camera for picture quality is done on the hardware side, *not* software.  In the software, it would essentially be equal to just taking one frame out of the video.